# Performing an action when an JMenuItem is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

So i have made a simple program with a basic menu at the top of the frame, Now i just need to put actions behind each JMenuItem. Im struggling to work the code out though, Here is what i thought would work:

```
JMenu file_Menu = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem fileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit Program"); 
file_Menu.add(fileExit);
fileExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JFrame hello = new JFrame("POPUP");
        hello.setSize(100,75);
        hello.setDefaultCloseOperation(hello.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hello.setVisible(true);
    }
});
main_Menu.add(file_Menu);
```

This doesn't seem to work though, I thought that this code would create a small popup window when the menu item is clicked.

Can any spot the bug because i cant seem to.

Comment: Will it print anything if you add System.out.println("hello!") to the beginning of your actionPerformed() method ?

Answer (score 7):

Suggestion: Instead of adding a separate `ActionListener`, just use `AbstractAction`:

```
JMenuItem fileExit = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Exit Program") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JFrame hello = new JFrame("POPUP");
        hello.setSize(100,75);
        hello.setDefaultCloseOperation(hello.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hello.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

I'd also suggest, instead of setting `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` on the popup menu, you set it on the main frame of your application, and have the action simply call `theMainFrame.dispose()`.

Comment: What is this approach for action definition called? I was impressed with initialization blocks (not used here) on how to put [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#buttonActions) like `{putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "blah");}`. [Tutorials from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) usually derive a class etc. instead of writing it this way.  What are the pros/cons of defining it this way vs whatever usually pops-up from the [web search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523119/actionlistener-vs-abstractaction).

Comment: Somehow it seems it is suboptimal as it [leads to bulk up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448179/673826).

Comment: @mlt that's fine, just make it a named class, as suggested in that answer. my point wasn't about the anonymous class, just about extending `AbstractAction` instead of adding an `ActionListener` to a named `JMenuItem`. (Though I can imagine situations where the latter would actually make more sense.)

Answer (score 2):

You got it working, but you have another problem.

Don't do this:

```
hello.setDefaultCloseOperation(hello.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

When you close the pop-up frame, your entire JVM terminates.  Consult JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation javadocs for a more appropriate value.

Comment: Damn, your right. Lucky that was mentioned before i delved further into the development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give an instance of Action (extend from AbstractAction) to JMenuItem

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted it looks like it should work, but we can't see the entire context of how the menu item is being used.

Did you debug your code (with a System.out.println) to see if the ActionListener is being invoked?

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Forgot to add the actionPerformed method.

Comment: You can make sure the superclass' overridden `actionPerformed` function is provided correctly by preceding it with `@Override`.