# How do I add actions to multiple different JMenuItems?

Tags: java

I've made a `JFrame` with  `JMenuBar` and added all the items. Everything is working fine. What I want to know is how to add an action to open website URLs. I've added the method to open URLs, but how do I make each button open the websites I want?

Comment: add `ActionListener` to each `JMenuItem`

Comment: Post an [MCVE (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing an action when an JMenuItem is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726115/performing-an-action-when-an-jmenuitem-is-clicked)