# ActionListener vs AbstractAction

Tags: java, actionlistener, abstract-action

i am trying to learn more about event handling but everywhere i read about it,   it's mainly about how to use it so something happens but not how it works.

So far i know about 2 ways to make something happen when a button is clicked.

ActionListener:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { @override actionPerformed... });
```

and AbstractAction:

```
public class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
    public MyAction(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic) {
        super(text, icon);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Action", e);
    }
}

MyAction myAction = new MyAction(...);
myButton.setAction(myAction);
```

I know that i can write everything i want to happen into the `actionPerfomed()` method.

But since i do not know, what exactly happens in the background I can not tell if one has any advantage over the other or which one i should use in which situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you extend AbstractAction, you can't extend any other classes. In any case, you might want to avoid subclasses whenever you can.
I would personally recommend implementing the interface `ActionListener` and then adding an action Listener to your swing object (or whatever you listen on) while using the "this" keyword.

```
public class ClassName implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button = new JButton("click me");
    public ClassName() {
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
            //perform action
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you also add the `ActionListener`directly (by using `.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {});`, but by using `this`,you can group all actions together.

//edit: Another way would be using `MouseListener`, which can listen to any clicks on your object, therefore enabling you to also use swing objects like `JLabel` as "buttons" - however, if you use `JButtons`, this would be unnecessary effort, considering that `ActionListener` is way easier to use, and you don't have to create lots of classes (such as `mousePressed`, `mouseClicked`, `mouseReleased`, etc.). However, if you anyway need `MouseListener` somewhere, you might want to think about using them so all events are grouped together.
Note: I do NOT know if `ActionListener` and `MouseListener` are equally fast, or if one of these methods are better! If your program requires a lot of power already, you might want to use `ActionListener`, which i guess is the faster way, if any of the two solutions is the faster one.

Comment: Then would there ever be a situation someone would use a class that extends AbstractAction instead of implementing ActionListener?

Comment: @Flikk i don't think it makes a lot of sense to extend `AbstractAction` instead of implementing `ActionListener` - however, you *could* extend `AbstractAction` if you want to define your own subclass of it. For example, I once created a class that extends abstractAction because I wanted to create key bindings, and at some point a certain method required an "Action" as a parameter (`ActionMap.put(Object key, Action action`). I'm not too familar with the `Action` class, though, so maybe I wouldn't have needed it there either.

Comment: "but by using `this`, you can group all actions together." - This is not ideal in some cases, for example when the class implements an action for a lot of events: the `#actionPerformed()` method will be full of `if(e.getSource == thisbutton) {...} else if (e.getSource() == thatButton) {} else if (...)` that you can avoid by just using anonymous implementations of ActionListener or AbstractAction that do the single bit they are meant for and nothing else. It keeps different functionalities separated.